# android -using retrofit lib getting error in parsing the response

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit

I am new to Retrofit Lib.. but i read it's features so i inspired to use this..i have used [This link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/) and i am having response like following

```
{
   "Users":[
      {
         "firstname":"Mike",
         "lastname":"Dalisay",
         "username":"mike143"
      },
      {
         "firstname":"Jemski",
         "lastname":"Panlilios",
         "username":"jemboy09"
      },
```

I am also done this in interface

```
public void GetUser(Callback<List<Users>> respose);
```

But getting `04-28 07:05:13.613  32242-32242/package name I/System.out﹕ error.toString() = retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

My Users.class

```
public class Users {
//    @SerializedName(value="Users")
    String firstname;
    String astname;
    String username;
    public List<Users> user;

    public void setUsers(List<Users> users) {
        this.user = users ;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getAstname() {
        return astname;
    }

    public void setAstname(String astname) {
        this.astname = astname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


}
```

i have edited my class by following yozzy's answer and called it like

```
api.GetUser(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(UserResponse userResponse, Response response) {
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        loading.dismiss();

    }
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        System.out.println("error.toString() = " + error.toString());
    }
});
```

but getting `retrofit.client.Response@532aa440`

Comment: Users is of type Array, and i think you have declared as String

Comment: You typed `astname`, just try to add an 'l' :)

Comment: @MalteseFalcon i have made changes but no effect.

Comment: The object you made is invalid. You are defining the array of users inside the `User` object itself. It's like an inception :)
Take the time to understand the logic of your JSON response,and check @yozzy answer

Comment: `but getting retrofit.client.Response@532aa440`, pls use `response.body().string()` instead of `response.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON response starts with a { so it's an object.

Your interface should be like this :

```
public void GetUser(Callback<UserResponse> response);
```

And your model UserResponse should be like this :

```
public class UserResponse implements Serializable {

   private ArrayList<User> Users;

   public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return Users;
   }

   public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> Users) {
       this.Users = Users;
   }
}
```

And finally your User model :

```
public class User implements Serializable {

   private String firstname;

   public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
   }

   public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
       this.firstname = firstname;
   }
}
```

By the way Retrofit has been updated see this link : http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: i used api.GetUser(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(UserResponse userResponse, Response response) {
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        loading.dismiss();
       
    }
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        System.out.println("error.toString() = " + error.toString());
    }
});

Comment: but i am getting response like retrofit.client.Response@532aa440

Comment: To log your response : 

`for(User user : userResponse.getUsers()){
   Log.e("Response", user.getFirstname());
}`

Comment: get error on   for (Users user : userResponse.getUsers()) { that is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Your array of users is empty are you sure you have a success response ? Use an interceptor to log request and response. And please use Retrofit 2 instead of Retrofit 1.

Comment: will supported in api 18?

Comment: Yes I use it and my app reach API 17 to 23

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class Result{
private List<Users> Users;
}


public class Users {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String username;

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    }
```

And use the `Result class`.

```
public void GetUser(Callback<Result> respose);
```